# Passing Activity Context to Handler(fragment) for Toast

Tags: android-fragments, handler, android-context, android-toast

I'm trying to use a Toast message in a handler fragment class but I can't access the main class' context. The handler is in the same class as the main activity, PlayFrets(which is also the UI thread).I've read through the plethora of questions on this topic on stackoverflow, but almost every solution involves passing getActivity() or getActivity().getApplicationContext() into the context field of Toast. When I try this I get errors

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class PlayFrets extends Activity {
. 
.
.
    static Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){  
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg){ 
            if(msg.obj != null){                
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                   //error happens here on Toast message
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Background Thread sent "+  msg.what + " bytes: " + msg.obj,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
            }
        }
    };
}
```

These are my attempts at passing the context and the errors each variation generates.

```
Toast.makeText(PlayFrets.this.getActivity()...)
```

^^^The method getActivity() is undefined for the type PlayFrets

```
Toast.makeText(PlayFrets.this...)
```

^^^No enclosing instance of the type PlayFrets is accessible in scope

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext()...)
```

^^^The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}

**What is the proper way to pass the main activity's context into the handler fragement for use in a Toast message?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Activity` is a context itself. Instead of all things you try you should

- not create `static` handler - that's why your attempt to pass `PlayFrets.this` fails
- pass `PlayFrets.this` as context
- no need to call `runOnUiThread()` because handler handles messages on UI thread in presented case

Your handler code should look like this:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {  
    public void handleMessage(final Message msg){ 
        if(msg.obj != null){
                   Toast.makeText(PlayFrets.this, "Background Thread sent "+  msg.what + " bytes: " + msg.obj,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? There are multiple guides I've read, such as http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html, that explicitly say you should avoid using non-static inner classes to prevent a memory leak. Also, if my Handler is non-static then my call to it from another class (PlayFrets.mHandler.sendMessage()) will not work and gives the following error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field PlayFrets.mHandler". Is there a solution that keeps the Handler static?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. As for the call from another class, pass instance of the handler to another class and do not reference it statically.

Comment: @Cody I've looked at the guide you've reference and, obviously, the guide makes sense. However you didn't follow the guide. For example, pay attention that in the guide `MyHandler` class is static, but variable that holds its instance, `mHandler`, is not static. Reference to the activity is passed to `MyHandler` in the constructor and later used as a context that you were looking for... But even before all that you should ask yourself whether resource leak described in the article applies to your case. Remember most important design pattern: simpler is better.

Comment: The potential for a leak applies to my case because my worker thread is constantly sending data(in an infinite loop) to the handler in the UI thread, therefore when the main activity is killed it is still possible for the Handler to hang around if there are messages in the Looper que from the worker thread. @ Your first comment, I tried this and it appears to be working somewhat but it is interfering with other elements of my program in inconsistent ways. Would an AsyncTask be more appropriate than using threads/handlers for my need for constant data being sent to the UI thread?

Comment: Did it solve your issue: "Passing Activity Context to Handler(fragment) for Toast"? If so please mark question as answered. If resource leak applies to you use the method proposed by the aforementioned guide and keep `handler` in `WeakReference` in your worker thread. AsyncTask is implemented with thread I think so it should not make a difference.

Comment: Well it did solve the issue but as a result is created a few more issues. Nonetheless your feedback gave me good insight into what I'm trying to accomplish so I gave you the completed answer. Thanks for the help.